# How to troubleshoot slow communication when using the Python HTTPServer module?

Tags: python, tcp, http-post

I am putting together an http-post server client example in order to send and request data from a client to a server that handle multiple connections.  I am using the HTTPServer module from the standard library. The code seems to work fine, but the communication slows down randomly. I have checked the communication traffic using Wireshark and I can see some strange messages going on.

I have checked different solutions on internet, but I have not found anything unusual in my code.

The code for the client it is just a simple http post request

Server code:

```py
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)

        data = {
            'ids': [5, 6]
        }

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(data).encode())

        return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

test = HTTPServer((SV_HOST, SV_PORT), Handler)
test.timeout = 5

print('Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop')
test.serve_forever()
```

Here are the Wireshark messages that I see:

[image: Wireshark GUI screenshot showing various messages]

I would appreciate if someone can clarify what I am doing wrong, if there is something wrong. Is "TCP segment of a reassembled PDU" normal?